# Problema al eliminar elementos de un array

Tags: javascript

*Hola , he estado intentado como hacer para eliminar los elementos de un array , y aun no puedo intentando como 2 horas...*

**Se trata de una string que es ingresada por un input text(siempre de la forma texto [algo],ese algo pueden ser numeros o letras lo que sea, que luego lo transformo a array con split() y busco donde comienza el primer corchete y el segundo , luego le resto el indice del primer corchete al indice del segundo y le sumo 1 para que cuando los borre con splice , se borren todos los elementos entre los corchetes incluyendo a estos mismos , puse en comentario el codigo que no me funciona , osea el splice, porfavor ayuda!!**

```js
function rec(nombre) {

//var d = nombre.value;
var get = document.getElementById('nack').value;
var usuario = get; // string
 var a = usuario.split(''); // Transformo a array
 var b = a.indexOf('[') + 1; // busco el indice del primer corchete
 var c = a.indexOf(']'); // busco el indice del segundo corchete
 var indices = (c - b) +1; // operacion para sacar los indices
 



 for ( b;b< c; b++) {
       
   document.write(parseInt(a[b]));
  

 // a[b].splice(b, c); <----- No me funciona

   

  
 }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<input type="text" id="nack" placeHolder="nickname"/>
<input type="button" onclick="rec(this.value);"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDITO: También lo he hecho de otro modo que es este:**

```js
function rec(nombre) {

var d = nombre.value;
var get = document.getElementById('nack').value;
var usuario = get; // string
 var a = usuario.split(''); // Transformo a array
 var b = a.indexOf('['); // busco el indice del primer corchete
 var c = a.indexOf(']'); // busco el indice del segundo corchete
 if (b == -1 && c == -1) {
 
  var indices = (c - b); // operacion para sacar los indices
 }
else {
var indices = (c - b) +1; // operacion para sacar los indices

}




var fr = a[indices];
 var eliminar = a.splice(b, indices); // elimino
 var volver = a.join(''); // vuelvo a convertir en string*/

usuario = volver;
document.write(usuario);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>

</script>
<form>
<input type="text" id="nack" placeHolder="nickname"/>
<input type="button" onclick="rec(this.value);"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**El problema está en que necesito borrar solo los corchetes que dentro tengan numeros y pues ya nosé como hacerlo , he probado con** `typeof a[b] == 'number'` **y tampoco , y por eso creo que la segunda forma no me ayuda en esto , ya que se necesita un for para recorrerlas, pero ya no me quedan ideas!!!**

**POSTDATA: POR EJEMPLO SI HAY MAS DE 1 PARENTESIS CON NUMEROS OSEA:
jugador [234] [42] , que tambien se puedan eliminar ambos valores y que si hay 2 o más pero uno de ellos es string , que solo se borren los que tienen numeros osea:
jugador [hola] [42], se borraria solo el 42 
porfavor si alguien sabe que me ayude!!**

***EJEMPLOS PARA ENTENDERME MEJOR:***

*1)*

```
 Voy y me coloco el nombre "Pepe [soy pro] [42]"

el juego automáticamente me elimina el '[42]' dejando como nombre solamente "Pepe [soy pro]"
```

*2)* Voy y me coloco el nombre "Pepe [17] [42]"

```
el juego automáticamente me elimina el '[42]' y el '[17'] dejando como nombre solamente "Pepe"
```

Comment: La verdad es que no acabo de entender lo que pretendes hacer. ¿Quieres coger el texto introducido en el input y eliminar el texto que haya entre corchetes?
Quizás si pones un ejemplo se entienda mejor.

Comment: El problema está en que necesito borrar solo los corchetes que dentro tengan numeros y pues ya nosé como hacerlo

Comment: @AsierVillanueva ya edite mi pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar expresiones regulares:

```js
function rec(nombre) {
  var re = /(\[\d+\])/g;
  var usuario = document.getElementById('nack').value;
  console.log(usuario);
  var result = usuario.replace(re, '');

  document.write(result);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>

</script>
<form>
<input type="text" id="nack" placeHolder="nickname"/>
<input type="button" onclick="rec(this.value);"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: bua, muchisimas gracias me ha ido de maravilla , me podrias explicar el código porfavor?

Comment: La variable re es una expresión regular que define un patrón de uno o más números entre corchetes (más información: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
El método replace utiliza la expresión regular para buscar todas las apariciones de este patrón en la cadena y reemplazarlo por una cadena vacía.

Comment: como podría usar esa expresion regular en un if ?

Comment: Si te refieres a comprobar en un if si una cadena cumple la expresión regular deberías utilizar el método test: if (re.test(cadena) { .... }